# How to create a new set of all elements that are in only one of multiple sets?

Tags: python, list, set, difference

I need the code to:

1. scan all elements of four different sets
2. put values that only appear uniquely in one set and not the others inside a new set

Example:

A{1,2,3,4,5}

B{1,2,3,4,6}

C{1,3,4,7}

D{1,8,9}

Set E would look like: {5,6,7,8,9}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about pooling all the sets (allowing for duplicates), counting the elements, and then take elements that occur only once?

```py
import itertools
import collections

A = {1,2,3,4,5}
B = {1,2,3,4,6}
C = {1,3,4,7}
D = {1,8,9}

cnt = collections.Counter(itertools.chain(A, B, C, D))
E = {k for k, v in cnt.items() if v == 1}
print(E) # {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

---

If you are somewhat reluctant to import modules, the following is equivalent:

```py
A = {1,2,3,4,5}
B = {1,2,3,4,6}
C = {1,3,4,7}
D = {1,8,9}

cnt = {} # prepare an empty list
for s in [A, B, C, D]: # loop over sets
    for x in s: # for each element in set s
        cnt[x] = cnt.get(x, 0) + 1 # increment the counter

E = set(k for k, v in cnt.items() if v == 1) # set consisting of singleton elements
print(E) # {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: The `map(list, )` is wholly unnecessary (you can `chain` `set`s just fine), and since they're not already in an iterable, putting them in one just to use `from_iterable` is... odd. `itertools.chain(A, B, C, D)` would be shorter and simpler. Also, just use a set comprehension, rather than `set`-ifying a genexpr: `E = {k for k, v in cnt.items() if v == 1}`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are totally right! Thank you so much. I am learning more and more by answering questions :)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, your advice worked. I am now wondering if I wanted to do this exact same thing, but scan for numbers where they exist in 2 out of the 4 sets, how I would change the code?

Comment: @lukan Try `set(k for k, v in cnt.items() if v == 2)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to unpack all the sets into a list. Then iterate over a union of them all getting their counts:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5}
b = {1,2,3,4,6}
c = {1,3,4,7}
d = {1,8,9}

joined = [*a, *b, *c, *d]

result = {i for i in set.union(a, b, c, d) if not joined.count(i) - 1}
```

---

```
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

This can be made more efficient if you use `collections.Counter` for `joined` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from collections import Counter

result = {i for i, c in Counter(chain(a, b, c, d)).items() if c == 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop on sets and accumulate a unique and common set to extract the desired result:

```
A={1,2,3,4,5}    
B={1,2,3,4,6}    
C={1,3,4,7}    
D={1,8,9}

unique,common = set(),set()
for S in (A,B,C,D):
    unique = (unique|S) - (S&common) # add set, remove duplicates
    common |= S                      # track seen items
    
print(unique)
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```